# How do I log the voterID after the user clicked the log in button?

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, ms-access

I am creating a simple voting system in `C#` with Access Database. I need to edit the Voting Status of the user after he votes, and I have the code below. How do I keep track of the currently logged in `voterID` of the user? That I need to use in this `WHERE VoterID=?`.

```
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var cmmand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tbl_voter SET VotingStatus=? WHERE VoterID=?",conn))
    {
        cmmand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", 1);
        cmmand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", "VoterID");
        cmmand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by currently logged in voterID? If you are referring to user name of person logged in on win operating system then you can use `System.Environment.UserName`

Comment: from where are you getting VoterID..

Comment: @SreenathGanga from here [link](http://imgur.com/a/cxo5I) as you can see from the database, i need to get that VotingStatus field with a check every time the user clicks vote button.

Comment: @kashi_rock in this [link](http://imgur.com/a/cxo5I) table

Comment: There are several ways to do that but it depends on you that how you want to implement. For example, you can create a "Voter" object and set required properties on successful login e.g. userid, username, first name, last name etc. use it in your entire login session and dispose it on logout or application close

Comment: @Theodore....How is Voterid available in system ..means how can System know which user is voting... are you using any LoginScreen or you using windows login?

Comment: After login, you can save the userID in variable, wouldn't that satisfy your needs

Comment: @kashi_rock sorry I am new to c# how do I do that?

Comment: @SreenathGanga I am using my own login screen using windows forms.

Comment: @Theodore see my answer..may have syntax error since not test in IDE but concept is ok

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Loginpage. I think you may be getting username and password from the Textbox and then sending it to Database to verify it.

First Create a Static variable in Program.cs

```
public static int VoterID= 0;
```

Then when Login is Successfull fill the VoterID variable  with the voterid of loggedin person in the login form itself

```
  Program.VoterID=int.Parse ( getVoteridof(txtusername.text,txtpassword.text).ToString());
```

Declare the method below

```
 public  Object getVoteridof(String username,String password)
        {
            Object returnValue;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ArtConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString()))
            {



                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "Select VoterID from tbl_voter where Uname=@param1 and Pword=@param2";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", password);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();

                returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
```

Now in your Voting Function

```
{
            conn.Open();
            using (var cmmand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tbl_voter SET VotingStatus=? WHERE VoterID=?",conn)) {
            cmmand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", 1);
            cmmand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Program.VoterID);
            cmmand.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: I forgot to tell u that I am using OleDB connection

Comment: there is an error in     `Program.VoterID=int.Parse ( getVoteridof(txtusername.text,txtpassword.text)); ` it says cannot convert from object to string

Comment: Updated Answer     Program.VoterID=int.Parse ( getVoteridof(txtusername.text,txtpassword.text).ToString());

Comment: shows an error here [link](http://imgur.com/a/cvT35) do i change the `"artconnectionstring"` ?